# C++ class public function that returns a pointer but doesn't allow deleting that pointer?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, delete-operator

```
template<typename T>
class SmartBuffer {
    int capacity;
    MyArray<T> *data;

public:

    SmartBuffer() {
        capacity = 0;
        data = nullptr;
    }

    void alloc(int nbElements) {            
        if (nbElements > capacity) {
            cout << "Allocating smart buffer\n";
            if (data!=nullptr) delete data;
            data = new MyArray<T>(nbElements + 1);
            capacity = nbElements + 1;                
        }
    }

    int size() {
        return capacity;
    }

    MyArray<T>* getBuffer() const {
        return data;
    }

    MyArray<T>* getBuffer() {
        return data;
    }
};
```

Basically, this class is used for pre-allocation of data, since `new[]` and `delete[]`(and `cudaMalloc` and `cudaFree`) are slow and makes up a significant portion of running time in my problem.

So, I wish to return a pointer to a `MyArray` object, the caller can modify the object freely. But it **must not** be allowed to delete the data. Basically, only a `SmartBuffer` object can delete it's own data.

Is there anyway to do this in C++ other than having another wrapper class and remove the delete operator like below?

```
void operator delete (void *p) = delete;
```

Comment: Side note: no need to test for `nullptr` in `if (data!=nullptr) delete data;`, as it is always safe to call `delete` on a `nullptr` pointer.

Comment: If a function returns a raw (non-`void`) pointer, nothing can technically prevent a caller from using that pointer in a `delete` expression, other than a non-accessible destructor. Misuse of that pointer gives undefined behaviour.   Usually, this is handled with documentation  (i.e. documented that the function returns a pointer that should not be released, and the caller must follow the documented rules). And having an `operator delete()` in a wrapper class is not a solution - a classes `operator delete()` is a function called *as part of the machinery* of a `delete` expression.

Comment: @prapin O.O for some reason I've always remembered "deleting nullptr = bad" for some reason. Probably from java

Comment: @bloody normally it would be good enough. Unfortunately, MyArray is used normally (without SmartBuffer) in other places.

Comment: @Peter that sounds like the answer :\ Could you write that out?

Comment: `getBuffer() const` doesn't seem to have any added value here...

Comment: @Eljay MyArray can be CPU or GPU array. It's just a placeholder in this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A natual solution would be to declare the destructor of `MyArray` as `private` and add `friend class SmartBuffer<T>` to its definition to allow only `SmartBuffer` to delete it.

However as you stated in a comment you're using `MyArray` in different contexts and want it to act "normally". Why won't you just implement another type. The least effort is to create an inheriting "wrapper" intended for use with `SmartBuffer`:

```
template <typename T> class SmartBuffer; //forward declaration (necessary before 'friend')

template <typename T>
class MySmartArray : public MyArray<T>
{
    private: ~MySmartArray() {}
    private: MySmartArray() {} //disallow also the constructor from external usage
    friend class SmartBuffer<T>;
};
```

Then you go:

```
template<typename T>
class SmartBuffer {
    int capacity;
    MySmartArray<T> *data;

public:
    ~SmartBuffer { delete data; } //SmartBuffer can delete MySmartArray

    //and replace everywhere MyArray to MySmartArray ...
    //...
};
```

Now an external user won't be able to delete it:

```
int main()
{
    SmartBuffer<int> buff;
    auto ptr = buff.getBuffer();
    delete ptr; // error: 'MySmartArray<T>::~MySmartArray() [with T = int]' is private within this context
    return 0;
}
```